# Git: pull and work with part of repository (specific directory)

Tags: git

I have a comparably big project which I am working alone for most of the time. Recently i added some html-templates that can be edited by colleagues without my attention to it. But the point is - they just dont need to pull whole project for that purpose, the just need one directory (`web/themes/templates/` for example). Any way to pull and push specific directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project so large that this is even a concern?  Also, I am concerned that maybe some of those other files might of interest to someone even if they are only editing certain HTML files.

Comment: Language barrier. It is not so large that there is no way to pull it full of course but people who should edit templates doesn't really need to be involved in file-structure and other boring things. It is just simply (for a first look) for me to figure out how to give them specific directory and teach how to push it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the separation you should setup a git submodule.
Using submodules is a repo-in-repo approach to handling modular projects;
in your case it seems wasteful (not worth it) to do this for a few templates.

Docu: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: In any case, it is better to know the technology than not. And, to be fair i had a plan to share folder which contains css-styles as well. So it is already sounds like a good case for sub-project.